# Is there any Bluemix service which can password protect a zip file?

Tags: zip, ibm-cloud

I am looking for a service which can take a zip file and return a password protected zip file?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. But I am sure you will find Libraries for most popular programming languages to do it easily.